# I can't figure out why my python chatbot can't properly respond how do I fix this?

Tags: python, pycharm, chatbot

Basically py python chatbot is pretty simple but I want it to be ablento have the feature to remember previous input, when you enter "how are you" followed by "im great," the bot will respond with "That's good to hear!" If you enter "how are you" again, it will be treated as a normal input, and the bot will respond accordingly. However, if you enter "im great" without the previous input of "how are you," the bot will ask you to rephrase.but the chatbot responds like this

```
User: how are you

Bot: I'm doing great. What about you?

User: im great

Bot: I'm sorry, I didn't understand. Can you please rephrase?

User: how are you

Bot: That's good to hear!

User:
```

Here's my code

```
class Chatbot:

    def __init__(self):

        self.user_input = ''

        self.previous_input = ''

        self.previous_response = ''

        self.database = self.create_database()

    def create_database(self):

        database = [

            {

                "input": "how are you",

                "responses": [

                    {

                        "response": "I'm doing great. What about you?",

                        "follow_up": "im great",

                        "follow_up_response": "That's good to hear!"

                    }

                ]

            },

            {

                "input": "exit",

                "responses": [

                    {

                        "response": "Goodbye!"

                    }

                ]

            }

        ]

        return database

    def process_input(self, user_input):

        self.user_input = user_input.lower()

        return self.generate_response()

    def generate_response(self):

        if self.previous_input == '':

            for intent in self.database:

                if self.user_input in intent['input']:

                    for response in intent['responses']:

                        self.previous_input = self.user_input

                        self.previous_response = response['response']

                        return self.previous_response

        elif self.previous_input != '':

            for intent in self.database:

                if self.user_input in intent['input']:

                    if 'follow_up' in intent:

                        if intent['follow_up'] == self.previous_input:

                            for response in intent['responses']:

                                self.previous_input = self.user_input

                                self.previous_response = response['follow_up_response']

                                return self.previous_response

                        else:

                            self.previous_input = ''

                            self.previous_response = "I'm sorry, I didn't understand. Can you please rephrase?"

                            return self.previous_response

        self.previous_input = self.user_input

        self.previous_response = "I'm sorry, I didn't understand. Can you please rephrase?"

        return self.previous_response

# Create an instance of the chatbot

bot = Chatbot()

# Conversation loop

while True:

    user_input = input("User: ")

    bot_response = bot.process_input(user_input)

    print("Bot:", bot_response)

    if 'exit' in bot_response.lower():

        break
```

I tried updating the generate response function to try and make it properly handle the situations but after multiple iteration nothing properly worked

Comment: For input "im great" the condition `if self.user_input in intent['input']:` is never met.